# When does a type get promoted to an unsigned int?

Tags: c++, c, types, casting, integer-promotion

This [article](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) says:

> If all values of the original type can be represented as an int, the
>   value of the smaller type is converted to an int; otherwise, it is
>   converted to an unsigned int

All values of `signed/unsigned char` and `signed/unsigned short` can be represented as an `int`, so when does a type gets promoted to an `unsigned int`?

Comment: `char` and `short` may be the same size as `int`, in which case an `int` wouldn't be able to represent all values of an `unsigned char/short`

Comment: The linked article explicitely talks about [tag:c]. Would you like to choose a language tag, or want a [tag:c++] language definition rule, covering this?

Comment: @Praetorian ... nor neccessarily of `char`, as that could be unsigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `short` cannot be longer than an `int` but on some platforms it may be the same size. The same goes for `int` and `long`. This means that if the "smaller" one is unsigned, the "larger" one must be too.

Answer (score 2):

The article is using sloppy terminology. The source type doesn't have to be "smaller" than `int`. Here is what the C++11 standard says:

> A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, or `wchar_t` whose integer conversion
>   rank (4.13) is less than the rank of `int` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all
>   the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type `unsigned int`.

There are platforms on which, say, `unsigned short` and `int` are both 16 bits long. Nevertheless, `unsigned short` has **lower rank** than `int` by definition and is subject to integral promotion. In this case, `int` cannot represent all values of type `unsigned short`, so the promotion is to `unsigned int`.

Edit: C99 has similar wording:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may
>   be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is less
>     than or equal to the rank of `int` and `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an `int`;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the integer
>   promotions. 48) All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

Answer (score 0):

well, if sizeof(char) == sizeof(int), then unsigned char shall be promoted to unsigned int

Comment: And raw `char` too, if that happens to be unsigned.